# Using setter methods or direct reference to variable inside constructor?

Tags: java

Both methods work, however which is the proper way to do it?

**Method one:**

```
public class Object {
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public Object(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }
}
```

**Method two:**

```
public class Object {
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   //Changed this.name = name to setName(name)
   public Object(String name){
       setName(name);
   }
}
```

I've searched around but couldn't find an exact question that referred to this. If there is one, free to post the link and I'll remove the question

Comment: They are both proper. There are more than one way to do things. If I had to pick one, I'd take method 2 tbh.

Comment: although eclipse usually refactor the code for method #2, IMO #1 is better because there's less risk of any collateral effect if someone for some reason changes setName()

Comment: Note that you shouldn't call your class `Object`, even in simple snippets!

Comment: @Leo Very good point leo, I've posted that to the person who answered below

Comment: I've posted my POV as an answer, so we'll have an interesting way to debate these ideas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first thought was to use the setter in the constructor. So if you want to change how the name is stored, or if you want to add any other behavior while setting the name, you just have to change it once.

But thinking just a bit more on this, I think using direct access to the variable is better if the class is not *final* and the method is not *private*. Otherwise someone could extend your, override the method, causing your constructor to call their method with unpredictable behavior.

***Rule of thumb:*** *If the class is not final, you should only call private methods in the constructor.*

Comment: That does make sense, however check the second post that Leo has posted, if the function is changed, it may cause collateral effect to certain data. Method one ensures the data you put is directed to the variable itself?

Comment: So yea, direct assignment seems like the more appropriate thing to do as long as it's simple assignment

Comment: I would use the rule: if the class is not *final* and the method you are calling from the constructor is not *private*, avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

While using a setter in the constructor reduces code duplication, calling overrideable methods (ie non final / non private methods) in a constructor is discouraged - it can lead to weird bugs when extending a class.

Consider the following case (based off of your example):

```
public class Object {
   private String name;

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   //Changed this.name = name to setName(name)
   public Object(String name){
       setName(name);
   }
}
```

With the following subclass:

```
public class SubObject extends Object {
   private String Id;

   @Override
   public void setName(String name) {
       super.setName(name + Id);
   }

   public SubObject(String name){
       super(name);
       this.id = "1";
   }
}
```

Creating an instance of `SubObject` will cause a null pointer, as `setName()` is called in the constructor, but the implementation of `setName()` relies on the `Id` field having been initialized.

Someone extending a class should not have to go check the source code of the super class to ensure the constructor isn't calling overrideable methods.

Comment: This is a very good example of why not to use setter method unless it's a private or final method

Answer (score 3):

If all the setter and constructor do is a simple assignment, it doesn't matter which of the two ways you choose.

However, if you need to perform some validations before assigning the new value to the member, it makes sense to have that logic in a single place, which means calling the setter method from the constructor is the better option.

Comment: If he want to perform some validations he should use a factory method, so he can properly react if the passed argument is invalid.

Comment: @Tom Very true, the case I provided was simple assignment, it was more of a convention question. Doesn't seem to receive an absolute answer

Comment: @Tom Or he can do the validation in the setter and throw an exception in case of invalid input.

Comment: @Eran He could if he want. I personally avoid exceptions in the constructor (or any method it calls). A factory should care about valid arguments, not the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

I would NOT use the setter in the constructor. This because if someone added any other behavior while setting the name in the setter, I'd consider it a collateral effect.

Comment: Largely agree.  For example, often setters fire events and this may be problematic in a constructor.  Also, a subclass could override the setter and cause other issues.  OTOH, the setter might do some validation...

Comment: So from what it seems, the answer itself is fairly situational and there is no, right/wrong answer to it. However from what it seems direct assignment is the more appropriate thing to do

Answer (score 1):

If `setName()` coontains some inner logic about how the name should be set, then I would choose 2. On the other hand, if `setName()` contains some aditional code that needs to be run when name is set, i would choose 1.

Let me make a bit more complex situation so I can express my point:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean wasRenamed;

    //getters...

    public Person(String fullName) {
        ???
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        ???
    }
}
```

Here we have `Person`s with first and last names, also we want to keep record who was renamed and who not. Let's say `fullName` contains first and last name separated by space. Now let's look at 2 different approaches you provided in your question:

1. *Not* call `setFullName()` in costructor: This will lead to code duplicity (spliting `fullName` by space and assigning it to first and last name.
2. *Do* call `setFullName()` in costructor: This will add extra trouble with the `wasRenamed` flag, since `setFullName()` has to set this flag. (This could be solved by simply resetting the flag back to `false` in constructor after calling `setFullName()`, but let's say we don't want to do that)

So I would go with *a combination* of 1 and 2, and split the inner logic of setting the name and the additional code that needs to run before/after name is set into different methods:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean wasRenamed;

    //getters...

    private void setFullName0(String fullName) {
        //split by space and set fields, don't touch wasRenamed flag
    }

    public Person(String fullName) {
        setFullName0(fullName);
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        setFullName0(fullName);
        wasRenamed = true;
    }
}
```